# Hide rows in several sheets based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a working script that hides rows in multiple tabs of a Google Sheet based on the value in Column T (note, there are more tabs in the sheet that I don't want it to work from - just the ones in the script). My issue is, it unhides all of the hidden rows first and then re-hides them including the new one...is there an adaptation I can make to the script so that it leaves all the currently hidden rows hidden and just hides the newly updated one?

```
function hideRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var only = ['Franke Fault', 'Selecta Vending Machines', 'Vivreau'
];
if (only.indexOf(ss.getName()) == -1) return;
var r = ss.getRange('T:T');
var v = r.getValues();
for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
if (v[0, i] > 10)
ss.hideRows(i+1);
};
```

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:
I tested this and works for me

```
function hideRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var only = ['Franke Fault', 'Selecta Vending Machines', 'Vivreau','Sheet0' ];
  if (~only.indexOf(ss.getName())) {
    var v = ss.getRange(1, 20, ss.getLastRow()).getValues();
    v.forEach((r, i) => {
      if (r[0] > 10) {
        ss.hideRows(i + 1)
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Before:

| COL20 |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 15 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 7 |
| 2 |
| 12 |
| 4 |
| 6 |
| 17 |
| 0 |
| 4 |
| 0 |
| 7 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 19 |
| 9 |

After:

| COL20 |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 7 |
| 2 |
| 4 |
| 6 |
| 0 |
| 4 |
| 0 |
| 7 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 9 |

Keep in mind it hides them but it does not remove them if you try to copy and paste the then you will get all of the data and not just the hidden ones

Comment: Thanks so much @Cooper, this way still works in terms of hiding the rows (and to be honest is a little quicker to run!) but it's still unhiding the other rows and then re-hiding them...it's just a bit odd

Comment: Please explain in greater detail what you want.  I don't understand what they "other rows" are.  What are you trying to accomplish?  If your code does not work how can it serve as an example of what you want.  You need to provide a better explanation.

Comment: I thought I had been clear so I apologise.  I have a working code that is hiding rows where column T is greater than 10.  However when the code is run, the previous rows it has hidden where the row contains a value greater than 10 in column T...it unhides all of the rows and then rehides them.  So for example if yesterday it hid 5 rows and then today I ran it again to hide another 6...it would unhide the 5 rows and then rehide the 5 and the extra 6. My code does work...I just don't want it to unhide the previously hidden rows before it hides the others.

Comment: Ok I'll try to setup a test bed and see if I can resolve that problem. So really you just have one column of data with numbers in it.

Comment: Are you using onChange or and onEdit or any trigger?

Comment: Thanks Cooper - I appreciate your help.  I am using an onEdit trigger - not sure if onChange would be more appropriate?  It's basically a work spreadsheet for logged faults and when the fault has been dealt with and the ticket can be closed, a checkbox is ticked in Column P, which timestamps column O and then column T works out the number of days between the timestamp and "today".  If the ticket has been closed for more than 10 days, we can hide the row

Comment: Hi Cooper - I have decided they can just use the script that's working - it is doing the job so why not!  I will mark your answer as the "winner" because the script does work :).  Thanks so much again